# How to put fully transparent divs and text on semi-transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

[image: example]

I have a div with a background-image and a semi-transparent white background-color on top of it which acts as a filter.

Now, I want to add divs and some text which would basically "bypass" the filter so they are fully transparent. Is there a way to do this in css, or perhaps in Javascript or whatever?

I am using Bootstrap and jQuery, I'm also open to any libraries you might know that could help me here.

Edit:

Here's a fiddle I just made: https://jsfiddle.net/frbkLuoe/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="filter">
        <div class="transparent-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-image:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-RSAdi3NMMs8/VakWj_znRcI/AAAAAAAAAMI/lp19iktRyCw/s1600/Rent%2Broom%2Bstockholm.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
.filter {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.transparent-block {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

I want the .transparent-block div to be transparent. The problem is it inherits the background of its parent, so even if I set background-color:transparent; or background:none; it's still semi-transparent white.

Comment: Child elements will also have the same opacity as their patent (or even more if they have their own opacity value), you can't override that. You'll have to stack separate elements with different opacity.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`). Post the relevant HTML and CSS so we can help you further.

Comment: How about the other way? Using a semi-transparent background-image on top of a white background? [CSS-Tricks - Transparent Background Images](//css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Comment: If this is an actual website, I'm surprised they pulled this off honestly; I'm guessing your best chance would be putting canvas to work in some creative manner.

Comment: @pol I have added my html and css as an edit. However I'm not sure how pseudo elements could help me in this case, could you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try `background-color` CSS property, for semi transparent try rgba (red, green, blue, alfa)

```
    .transparent{
      background-color: transparent; //transparent 
    }
    .semi-transparent{
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); //semi-transparent white
    }
```